# Arduino splitting string to an array with delimeter

Tags: c++, arduino

Below is a simple code for reading incoming data from my power analyzer, im using gizduino+ ATMEGA 644p, it is an arduino clone.

```
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);  
String str;
void loop() {

if(Serial.available() > 0)
{
    str = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
    Serial.println(str);
 } 
}
```

what you can see below is the output in my serial monitor, im new in programming an arduino, my problem is that i need to get the 3rd index if that is going to be an array which is splitted by comma.

```
InRange, 0000.0,0000.0, 0000.0, 0.1055,229.39,0.0006,
InRange, 0000.0,0000.0, 0000.0, 0.1267,228.99,0.0006,
InRange, 0000.0,0000.0, 0000.0, 0.0633,229.00,0.0006,
InRange, 0000.0,0000.0, 0000.0, 0.0914,229.31,0.0006,
InRange, 0000.0,0000.0, 0000.0, 0.1126,228.88,0.0006,
InRange, 0000.0,0000.0, 0000.0, 0.0914,229.29,0.0006,
InRange, 0000.0,0000.0, 0000.0, 0.1055,229.34,0.0006,
InRange, 0000.0,0000.0, 0000.0, 0.1267,229.25,0.0006,
InRange, 0000.0,0000.0, 0000.0, 0.1041,230.03,0.0006,
InRange, 0000.0,0000.0, 0000.0, 0.0277,229.79,0.0006,
```

Comment: btw, im using arduino ide to program this

Answer (score 1):

many answers here already:

https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/1013/how-do-i-split-an-incoming-string

There isn't a straight forward way like in python or javascript. You'll need to parse the string until the character shows.